# AppArmor and bind-mounts

Tags: mount, apparmor, bind-mount

Can someone outline the semantics of AppArmor with respect to bind-mounted folders?

As I understand after reading the documentation ([1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor), [2](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/apparmor.html), [3](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/apparmor.7.html), [4](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page)) - yes, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with the 3.8 kernel - the policies are "attached to paths" (i.e. paths of programs that become processes when invoked).

So assume I have the folder `/home/joe/Public` and that has the location `/var/www/html/joe` bind-mounted to it.

Will I have to create a profile that covers the original *and* the bind-mounted, one of them (which) or is there something else I'd have to do or to consider?

Let's say there is a program `/var/www/html/joe/foo`, will the confinement still work when the profile/rule only mentions `/var/www/html/joe/foo`, but Joe decides to run it as `/home/joe/Public/foo`?

Links and other pointers will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a definitive reference nor direct experience, so this is not an authoritative answer.

AppArmor is based on paths (after resolving symbolic links, I believe). Paths don't care about mount points. An AppArmor rule for `/var/www/html/joe/foo` applies to a file accessed through that path. The path `/home/joe/Public/foo` may happen to designate the same file, but since it's a different path, the AppArmor rules for `/var/www/html/joe/foo` do not apply.

You'll have to define rules that cover all the bind-mount locations. You don't have to repeat your rules, however. You can tell AppArmor that a location is an [alias](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#Alias_and_rewrite_rules) for another.

```
alias /home/joe/Public -> /var/www/html/joe
```

I don't think you can use a wildcard to have one alias apply automatically to all users. For that, you can express your rules using variables.

```
@{WWW_DIRS} = /home/*/Public /var/www/html/*
…
@{WWW_DIRS}/foo …
```